# How do I send a job to a printer inside my HTML 5 app?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, hybrid

I need to be able to print content from my HTML 5 app directly from within the app it self. Here's my understanding of what I need to do, please correct me if I'm wrong:

- Have a button somewhere in the app that when clicked, executes some code that sends the data to the printer. Now, as the app is a HTML 5 app, I believe that would need to be converted into some format that the printer understands, if so, what would I look to convert it to?
- Once the data from the app has been taken and converted into a printer friendly format, I need to send it over to the printer. This could be done either a) from an email from the tablet to the printer's email address or b) via Google Cloud Printing which handles the print job for me.

Is that essentially it? Or am I missing some massive steps here? I've never done this before and can't find anything with any search that I do, all I seem to get back is existing Android app suggestions, but that's not what I need. Any input would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks!

Comment: by hybrid you mean phonegap?

Comment: Well I'm actually using Worklight but essentially, yes, PhoneGap underpins it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would be about it: you can just turn it into a paper friendly format and email it to the printers email adress or use Cloud Print, which isn't really that hard to get running.